# How do I get my question answered if I already edited it and I don't have enough points to put a bounty on it?

Tags: discussion, views

I have asked a question on Stack Overflow that I would really like an answer to. When I first posted the question, it only gained about 2 views from people beside myself and no answers or comments. After about an hour I edited the question and it has only gained 2 more views and still has no comments or answers on it.

This led me to wonder what I should do in this situation and situations like this in the future. I don't want to spend points for a bounty on this question and editing it has not gained me any insight to my question.

Because those are the only methods that I found that Stack Overflow suggests to gain more attention for a question, I wanted to ask users on Meta if they had any ideas on what is the best thing to do in this situation. **I (and many others) would greatly appreciate all ideas on what to do if you can't place a bounty on a question and editing it has not gotten enough views for someone to answer it, but you still want an answer to your question.**

Comment: **Patience**...it's a holiday weekend.

Comment: Posting it on Meta ... wait ... you've already done that.

Comment: ...but if it's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252655/how-to-send-streaming-video-and-audio-data-to-the-server) it seems **very** broad...

Comment: You only have one shot at making a good first impression, the question title is very, *very* important.  Otherwise a very good job, the question body is just like the title promises.  Don't change anything, you'll only get help from somebody that thinks the title is interesting.  That is going to take a while.

Comment: If you remove the bold from that last paragraph and make it **way** less broad, I'd be happy to help you out. (One-time offer only. Offer may expire any time at my whim.)

Comment: Aside from the broadness, there's still a few edits to be made: "HTML" and "Javascript" can be cased properly, the ["thanks" can be done away with](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), and "How to...?" is not a question and shouldn't end with a question mark. Plus the "How to" bit is just filler and can be removed.

Comment: Your question has only been up for 4 hours. Stop expecting instant gratification. Someone will answer your question if they know the answer, but you may have to wait until that someone comes along. If you can't be patient, hire someone and pay them to give you the immediate attention you seem to want. Remember when you're posting here that people are **donating** their time to help you solve your problem; you don't have the right to demand that it be done on your schedule.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, because people are most definitely not going to answer this question because the OP had the balls to say *thanks*! I would never answer a question from someone with such an offensive attitude, and neither should anyone else. And I most certainly immediately move away from any question which does not capitalize html to my personal preference − such clueless idiots can never be helped! [NO SOUP FOR YOU!](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/741/my-love-hate-relationship-with-stack-overflow-arthur-s-arthur-t-and-the-soup-nazi)

Comment: That wasn't what I meant, @Carpetsmoker, but I can understand how you could read it that way. You're right, the issues I pointed out are quite minor, and don't affect the answerability in the slightest. I was responding to the point made in the title here that "the question has already been edited". I wanted to suggest that the question can be _legitimately_ bumped again, by fixing the tidbits I mentioned (plus, I legitimately think the edit will make the question _better_).

Comment: Wait till tumbleweed grows...

Comment: At SO you get help for free. Don't complain if you get it slowly. Or not at all. If you want help quickly, pay for it.

Answer (score 7):

Bad timing is probably a factor. I don't have access to the Stack Overflow statistics, but here is the daily view count for [vi.stackexchange.com](https://vi.stackexchange.com/site-analytics):

[image]

See a pattern? The view count is always significantly  lower in the weekends. It's even lower still in the current Easter weekend.

I see no reason why the pattern for Stack Overflow view counts should be significantly different.

You also have to realize that you're asking a question which requires knowledge in a fairly specific and narrow field (WebRTC), and is comparatively difficult to answer. I actually looked at the very same problem about a year ago, and wasn't able to find a simple and straightforward solution for this (this doesn't mean it doesn't exist, just that it was more trouble than it was worth for my hobby project).

But ... you didn't tag your question with [getusermedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getusermedia) (24 followers) or [webrtc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webrtc) (656 followers). Many of the almost 700 people following these tags are probably *experts* in WebRTC and may have a good indication of how to solve your problem.

Instead you chose some fairly broad tags: [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), and [websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/websocket). Someone who knows about JavaScript, HTML5, or WebSockets may not know the first thing about WebRTC. Only [streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/streaming) is specifically related to your problem − but "streaming" is also very broad and an expert on streaming video with VLC may not know the first thing about WebRTC. There's nothing wrong with adding these tags as such, but you should always choose the most specific tags possible.

And you added some fairly useless tags: [serverside-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serverside-javascript) (very broad, almost useless; 63 followes), [client-side-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/client-side-scripting) (useless tag, 4 followers).

Comment: [here](http://i.imgur.com/983IUMy.jpg)'s the same graph for SO. Unsurprisingly, there's the same trend.